# How to use iframe in phonegap project?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I have created a phonegap project. In this project there is a page with a button integrated. This button refers to an url ("InAppbrowser: True").

I would like to integrate an iframe instead of a redirection.

I already tried:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
```

Unfortunately I don't know exactly how and where to use it.

(This is a .js file and it is under the following path app/module/custom/example.js)

```
example.js (code snippet) 

       content['iframe'] = {
          theme: 'button_link',
          text: 'register',
          path: 'https://www.google.de/',
          options: {
              iframe: true,
              //InAppBrowser: true
            }
       };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="QR" data-role="view" data-model="Your data model name"></div>
```

Please above code put in your HTML file

Then Below code put in your click button event

```
//Append iframe 
$("#QR").find(".view-content").append('<iframe id="ifrQR" src="" target="_parent"></iframe>');
var iFr1 = document.getElementById('ifrQR');
iFr1.src = "http://www.google.in";
var $if1 = $("#QR").find("#ifrQR");
$if1.load(function () {
     alert("iframe loaded");
});
```